# How do I log com.fasterxml.jackson errors with Quarkus?

Tags: json, parsing, logging, jackson, quarkus

I use Jackson to check and databind input JSON for a REST API, and I would like to log the error when the input doesn’t match a `@Valid` constraint.

However, the exceptions are throwned as a `Response` by the API but do not appear in Quarkus’ logs.

How do I log Jackson’s exceptions ?

Answer (score 1):

One has to create a handler for the Jackson exceptions, e.g. using [`ExceptionMapper`](https://howtodoinjava.com/resteasy/resteasy-exceptionmapper-example/).

The following example catches all exceptions of type [`JsonProcessingException`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-core/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/core/JsonProcessingException.html) (finer tuning is obviously possible), logs them as `SEVERE` (using [lombok’s `@Log`](https://projectlombok.org/features/log) annotation) and returns a `400 Bad Request` `Response` including the message.  Note that the function has to be `toResponse(Exception)`.

```
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper;
import javax.ws.rs.ext.Provider;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import lombok.extern.java.Log;

@Log
@Provider
public class MyJsonProcessingExceptionHandler implements ExceptionMapper<JsonProcessingException> {
    
    @Override
    public Response toResponse(JsonProcessingException exception) {

        log.severe(exception.getMessage());

        return Response.status(Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST).entity(exception.getMessage()).build();

    }
}
```

Do not forget the `@Provider` annotation so that the Exception handler acts as a filter on the REST API.
In principle other files of the project (including the controller) do not need to be modified, only this class in its own file.